# Automatic re-size of a webpage to fit monitor/resolution

Tags: resolution

I'm in the midst of designing a webpage, but doing it on a 22" monitor with a resolution of 1680x1050. In our work environment we are using a mix of 17" and 22" monitors and of course they are all at different resolutions. How would I need to code my page to able to automatically adjust to the size of the monitor? I'm hoping it can be done without objects being moved around, just scaling down everything to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the tips are,

1. Use % while defining the div size instead of pixels 
   2.Use em  in font-size instead of 12px,14px ...

fit the screen even for small screens- worth reading about this deeply . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design